# How can I use Seach and Filter classes from Google GenericDAO for seaching not mapped class objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, genericdao

I have Bridge class:

```
public class Bridge extends Attribute{
    String name;
    //getters and setters
}
```

this class used for mapping. 
Bridge.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pack.persistent.Bridge" table="bridge">
        <property name="name"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Attribute class also:

```
public class Attribute{
    String description;
    //gettors, setters & something else
}
```

When I use Google GenericDAO framework for searching some entity using filter I can search only by `name` field, but not by `description`.

How can I use `Search` and `Filter` classes from Google GenericDAO framework for seaching not mapped class objects?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the field description in Bridge.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pack.persistent.Bridge" table="bridge">
        <property name="name"/>
        <property name="description"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: but in this case will be added new field to my databese. I dont want it.

Comment: Hmm but how will you search for description if it doesn't fill up from the database. Is it being filled logically within the code ?

Comment: Hi, Kindly let me know if this solution helped or if you found better alternative.

Comment: Kindly let me know if the proposed solution helped you or if you had some problem with the proposed steps. If it has fulfilled the problem solution then kindly accept the solution.